# MapControllerRoute with multi level urls

Tags: asp.net-core, url, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to rewrite some of category urls to point to a specific view/controller.

I currently have this working pattern

For my category page I want my Urls to look like...

**/ladies/shoes/cat/12345**
But it be any number of levels

**/Ladies/shoes/sports-shoes/cat/1233**
Currently my url rewrite looks like this..

```
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "CategoryPage", pattern: "shop/{productName}/Cat/{id}", defaults: new { area = "shop", controller = "Category", action = "index" });
```

How do I handle my rewrite so productName can be multi level.

my controller only needs the id at the end, everything constructing the categories is just look and feel.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(long id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a work around by adding a catch all

app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "CategoryPage",
pattern: "shop/{controller=category}/{id}/{*categoryName}",
defaults: new { area = "shop", action = "index" });

this allows me to nest multiple levels.